# PostgreSQL convert float value to time, hh:mm

Tags: postgresql

I am converting from SQL server to PostgreSQL. I have a function that take a float and converts it to a time. For example if the float number is 12.5 it converts to 12:30. Is there anyway to do this in postgres?
Thanks

Comment: What if the number if 37.5?

Comment: Im actually not worried about hours, only minutes. So if you the input is 121.75 I could care less about the 121, I am just concerned with the .75 = :45, so output would be 121:45.

Comment: Still it will not make sense, lets say you have number like 37.37 then what? The point is what you are trying to achieve is not very clear.

Comment: Ok lets take hours out of this all together. I want take a decimal and convert it to a time so it the decimal was .25 I want time to be :15, if the decimal is .37 I want the time to be :22.

Comment: Check the answer from stas.yaranov!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select to_char(to_timestamp((12.5) * 60), 'MI:SS');
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/4399)**

If `seconds` is the only thing you need, you can write something like this:

```
select date_part('second', to_timestamp((12.37) * 60))::int;
```

or

```
select to_char(to_timestamp((12.37) * 60), 'SS');
```

Comment: There is some serious voodoo magic going on here! +1 for a great answer :D

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 6.75*'1 HOUR'::INTERVAL
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my personal case, this worked:

```
to_char(to_timestamp(table.time_stamp/1000), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

You can even change the date format (for instance, 'mm/dd/yyyy' or 'dd-mm-yyyy) and the space between the date and the time (another example: 'dd/mm/yyyy | HH24:MI:SS')